# R: Fit a trendline to these points in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting

I have measurements for my dependent and independent variable across 4 different experimental sites

```
> df
        SITE     depend  independ
    1      b  168.00000  6.441205
    2      b  175.00000  6.939212
    3      b  231.00000  6.370073
    4      b  185.00000  6.816244
    5      b   56.00000  4.839825
    6      b  295.00000  7.032590
    7      b  277.00000  7.473761
    8      b  126.00000  5.791581
    9      b  391.00000  8.209857
    10     b  200.00000  5.607706
    11     b  701.00000  9.457697
    12     b  371.00000  7.509605
    13     b   96.00000  5.938662
    14     b  259.00000  7.868018
    15     b  456.00000  8.397162
    16     b 1382.00000 12.085675
    17     b  323.00000  7.136464
    18     b   96.00000  5.624912
    19     b  346.00000  7.483332
    20     b  799.00000  9.395876
    21     b 1060.00000 10.792450
    22     b  544.00000  7.750952
    23     b  173.00000  6.157235
    24     b  196.00000  6.967660
    25     b  366.00000  6.851160
    26     b  356.00000  7.438638
    27     b  277.00000  7.017364
    28     b   74.00000  5.881512
    29     b  119.00000  6.370771
    30     b  254.00000  6.694148
    31     b  490.00000  7.915398
    32     b  254.00000  6.936110
    33     b  182.00000  6.252873
    34     b   89.00000  6.130857
    35     b  357.00000  7.154955
    36     b  499.00000  6.590502
    37     b  184.00000  6.546551
    38     b   41.00000  5.147197
    39     b   40.00000  5.668956
    40     b  208.00000  5.465280
    41     b  283.00000  4.424971
    42     b  224.00000  4.801846
    43     b   54.00000  4.065652
    44     b   52.00000  3.856986
    45     b  199.00000  4.183085
    46     b  213.00000  4.173327
    47     b  260.00000  4.882182
    48     b  111.00000  4.198152
    49     b   33.00000  3.884470
    50     b  268.00000  5.079467
    51     b  110.00000  3.325862
    52     b  104.00000  4.051622
    53     b  154.00000  4.247760
    54     b   25.00000  3.762566
    55     b  136.00000  3.752807
    56     c  241.56199 19.615185
    57     c  350.59535 24.304213
    58     c  214.17054 24.748324
    59     c  182.54479 17.528364
    60     c  236.96800 21.447088
    61     c  271.30102 22.423033
    62     c  185.08586 15.571394
    63     c  160.93738 22.328360
    64     c  197.55959 22.180291
    65     c  103.83524 17.468660
    66     c  142.56036 23.997938
    67     c   81.42678 19.299329
    68     c   84.22605 17.881147
    69     c  115.94955 24.141446
    70     c  133.42529 23.062898
    71     c  102.53631 20.277638
    72     c   84.36548 30.151952
    73     c   84.47937 21.096182
    74     c  236.27805 30.099155
    75     c  349.90029 35.396363
    76     c  444.88595 30.248578
    77     c  296.82142 24.704304
    78     c  510.57317 39.110463
    79     c  486.37477 30.426705
    80     c  236.41881 29.255599
    81     c  355.17601 42.052473
    82     c  607.77522 38.420525
    83     c  232.72935 27.145563
    84     c  195.29648 38.246792
    85     c  268.11658 28.665716
    86     c  193.83150 25.691579
    87     c  190.96397 37.430981
    88     c  330.81237 30.617868
    89     c  227.35598 28.136638
    90     c  217.53775 45.928556
    91     c  326.69894 35.236348
    92     a   84.82300  7.890941
    93     a   65.92033  9.602303
    94     a  112.02938 12.577319
    95     a  102.07078  9.691760
    96     a   37.54533  9.783016
    97     a   92.96748  8.648471
    98     a   84.82300  6.534176
    99     a   65.92033  8.798907
    100    a  112.02938 10.611139
    101    a  102.07078  8.045100
    102    a   37.54533  8.198559
    103    a   92.96748  7.025727
    104    a  277.99407  8.703563
    105    a  274.67549 10.283912
    106    a  209.35391 11.160171
    107    a  374.62773 10.802339
    108    a  189.12355  9.353084
    109    a  169.75574  8.936873
    110    a  114.04921  8.538088
    111    a  130.17711 10.294958
    112    a  157.86700 13.335407
    113    a  132.83674  9.725718
    114    a  160.14794  9.982123
    115    a   88.51967  8.477415
    116    a   55.69747  7.447332
    117    a   44.33433  8.652240
    118    a   64.56533 11.329548
    119    a  186.16691  8.889405
    120    a  116.22274  9.639093
    121    a   54.38541  7.864175
    122    a   32.72340  4.700851
    123    a   72.46003  6.249158
    124    a   91.10478  9.106591
    125    a   33.92287  5.025721
    126    a   59.61350  6.111414
    127    a   63.97190  4.678834
    128    a  315.13820  9.481181
    129    a  321.52545  9.871237
    130    a  154.74091 11.628064
    131    a  313.95592 11.068721
    132    a  127.80241  8.436874
    133    a  166.27027  8.384337
    134    a   76.69727  8.832208
    135    a  126.71580 11.029189
    136    a   91.79080 14.895407
    137    a  151.48970 12.856855
    138    a  195.59343 11.122149
    139    a   74.91341  9.317945
    140    a  295.98038  8.836945
    141    a  166.43070 10.310140
    142    a  154.86179 13.008521
    143    a   61.32212  8.405404
    144    a  187.58412  9.435029
    145    a   72.45953  6.694838
    146    d   42.26709        NA
    147    d   67.27785        NA
    148    d   48.16153        NA
    149    d   59.61941        NA
    150    d   46.86858        NA
    151    d   67.23354        NA
    152    d   37.77909        NA
    153    d   67.38458        NA
    154    d   33.75093        NA
    155    d   53.47952        NA
    156    d   44.86217        NA
    157    d   61.34711        NA
    158    d   47.07810  3.584784
    159    d   76.03665  7.017740
    160    d   52.12276  3.198352
    161    d   67.70569  5.703212
    162    d   51.54876  3.691451
    163    d   80.90385  7.080591
    164    d   42.34507  4.628310
    165    d   85.94787 10.013365
    166    d   39.04737  4.064594
    167    d   60.19088  5.686637
    168    d   49.23514  4.251856
    169    d   71.77600  6.751174
    170    d   55.90435  5.171524
    171    d   91.84596 10.160686
    172    d   63.31703  5.462032
    173    d   82.71376  8.437648
    174    d   61.36583  5.190954
    175    d   99.50947  9.114059
    176    d   49.37328  6.218972
    177    d   99.14676  9.550849
    178    d   44.57117  4.741055
    179    d   71.89609  7.256575
    180    d   56.47511  5.391315
    181    d   87.06737  8.078044
    182    d   65.56232  6.499106
    183    d  104.74657 10.127041
    184    d   72.55353  6.557808
    185    d   80.90207  7.438215
    186    d  102.16351  6.449129
    187    d   90.54294  9.340280
    188    d   54.45511  7.369644
    189    d  136.64572  8.907776
    190    d   51.85764  6.122434
    191    d   98.67447  6.588543
    192    d   67.20106  6.847232
    193    d  120.43387  9.726845
```

`df` looks like this:

[image]

The hypothesis was that the dependent variable would decrease as the independent variable increases, but after a first look it seems that the hypothesis might be wrong.

I must admit my inexperience, so please, help me decide which type of trendline I could add to my points. Is it exponential? Looks slightly like an L-shaped. Or just scattered with no trend at all?

I have tried to fit a gam model, but the curve does not fit the upper left points.

```
ggplot(df,aes(independ,depend)) + geom_point(aes(col=SITE)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x), size = 1,col="red",se=F)
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like threshold regression or quantile regression. I agree that the question is better suited to Cross Validated.

Comment: Use +geom_smooth()

Comment: When I do, using loess, gam or polynomial, the upper left points of the graph are completely left out.

Comment: Don’t you think it might somehow resemble an infinite L?

Comment: I realize that the other copy of this doesn't yet have an answer (like the "duplicate" message says), but there's no point in having the same question posted twice. When a post should be on a different site, it's better to flag it and wait for it to move than repost it, since eventually the original will turn up as well (as happened here).

Comment: Sorry, I created a new post with an updated introduction, data and image here as suggested by other, and eventually the old post was moved here as well